# jruby dotenv-rails code converter not found (UTF-8 to UTF-8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, utf-8, rubygems, jrubyonrails

When I installed dotenv-rails i my app in jruby (I use windows) I could not start the Puma server because I have this error :

```
web.1  | Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError: code converter not found (UTF-8 to UTF-8)
web.1  | 1.0/lib/dotenv.rb:14
web.1  | ivesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36
web.1  |         require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
web.1  | /gems/shared/gems/puma-2.16.0-java/lib/puma/runner.rb:114
```

I don't know what can I do to continue my app.

Is anybody can help me please ? Maybe can I use another gem to make the same thing but I need a tutorial to make it.

Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with jRuby not dotenv.

For reference see
https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/233
and 
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3647

It appears to be fixed and should be included in jRuby 9.1.0.0

If you change your dotenv to rely on 2.0.2 then you should be good to go.

`gem "dotenv", "2.0.2"`